# WPF MarkupExtension to Determine Assembly in which XAML is Embedded

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions, baml

I have a WPF project (in .NET 4.0) with XAML resources embedded in as assembly as Pages. In the XAML, I need to have MarkupExtension that is declared in another assembly that has no specific knowledge of the assembly with the XAML.

Now, I need this MarkupExtension to be able to access the assembly in which the XAML is embedded. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of playing around, I worked it out:

```
public override object ProvideValue( IServiceProvider serviceProvider )
{
    var contextProvider = (IXamlSchemaContextProvider)serviceProvider.GetService( typeof( IXamlSchemaContextProvider ) );
    var type = contextProvider.SchemaContext.GetType().Assembly.GetType( "System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext" );
    var property = type.GetProperty( "LocalAssembly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic );
    var assembly = (Assembly)property.GetValue( contextProvider, null );
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: You need the name/path of the assembly to use it in XAML. ([example](http://www.bryanewert.net/journal/2010/6/8/how-to-create-an-external-markupextension-assembly.html))

Your way is to use the MarkupExtension in the code-behind by dynamically loading your needed assembly.

Comment: There must be some 'context' in which the MarkupExtension is being called or XAML/BAML is being loaded.